# Cannot install pyodbc in docker and getting error command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python-3.x, azure, docker, azure-functions, docker-build

I'm trying install pyodbc in docker running inside linux container
But I'm getting the following error

[Click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLlDC.png)

```
 src/pyodbc.h:56:10: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
   #include <sql.h>
            ^~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyodbc
```

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:2.0
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
COPY . /home/site/wwwroot
FROM ubuntu
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install gcc mono-mcs && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
FROM  python
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip
# RUN /usr/bin/pip -r /home/site/wwwroot/requirements.txt
# WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
COPY --from=0 /home/site/wwwroot /home/site/wwwroot
RUN cd /home/site/wwwroot && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Note: I'm going push the code to the azure functionapp in linux machine

Comment: I’ve never seen gcc print out an error message with an image.  Can you replace the link with the actual text of the error message you’re getting?  (Not a screen shot, the text.)

Comment: please see the updates question

Comment: Please don't post *pictures* of text. Just include the full text in your question. Links to external sites expire and become useless, and images are inaccessible to those relying on screen readers or similar technology to interact with Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 24):

I had the same issue, I added the below code in my docker file, and it started working. Microsoft docker image is missing `unixodbc-dev`, so you need to install separately using the below command.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    unixodbc-dev \
    unixodbc \
    libpq-dev
```

Comment: TO EVERYONE ELSE - UPDATE AS OF 2023-DEC, This is, by far, the working answer amidst other similar questions. I still have challenges installing the msodbcsql18 though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13):

This is the setup that worked for me:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.2-slim-buster

# install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get -y install gcc \
  && apt-get -y install g++ \
  && apt-get -y install unixodbc unixodbc-dev \
  && apt-get clean
```

And the pyodbc package was installed successfully.

Comment: This solution works for me for python 3.9.10-slim-bullseye

Answer (score 5):

The error is:

```
 src/pyodbc.h:56:10: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
   #include <sql.h>
```

This is telling you that you are missing a file `sql.h`. Looking at [the documentation for PyODBC](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install), it appears to require the UnixODBC development environment.

There are installation instructions at the above link for most major distributions. You will need to update your Dockerfile to install the `unixodbc-dev` package.

Comment: This answer is not *entirely* unhelpful, but without pointing the OP to the solution, you're just helping him in reading the error code.  This gets him 1% of the way to the solution, but @Karthekeyan's answer is far more helpful.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson I 100% disagree with you. Karthekeyan's answer doesn't explain anything and instead just spoonfeeds the answer. Whereas this answer by larsks provides a more in depth explanation. Also it basically spells out exactly what needs to be done (updating the Dockerfile) so I would say it gets the asker 99% of the way to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

This link is also helpful, you are missing mandatory files to needed to install. Add the below command for Debain to Dockerfile , the link has all solutions

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc unixodbc-dev

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/165

Answer (score 0):

The consolidated list of dependencies needed for pyodbc can be found in the documentation. Make sure **all** of these are installed.

[PYODBC installation documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install)